# How to get specific elements to be repeated in XSD

Tags: xsd

I am trying to pass few elements and 1 element(product) which contains sku and quantity should repeat but when i am trying this whole all 6 are repeating in the payload.I tried in many ways, it doesn't work and I can't find the problem.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="customReference"/>
    <xs:element name="shippedFromCustomId"/>
    <xs:element name="shippedToCustomId"/>
    <xs:element name="orderNumber"/>
    <xs:element name="referenceNumber"/>
    <xs:element name="products">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="product" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="sku"/>
                <xs:element name="quantity"/>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Hope this clarifies where i stuck at, Please share if you have any related information.
Thanks in advance!!``

Comment: Add maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" to root element

Comment: Could you please edit your question and provide an example of a problematic XML?

Comment: @BhavO you can't specify these attributes in an element declared globally

Comment: Hi,@sergioFC i need to achieve this XML                                                    <root>
<customReference></customReference>
<shippedFromCustomId></shippedFromCustomId>
<shippedToCustomId></shippedToCustomId>
<products>
<product>
<sku></sku>
<quantity></quantity>
</product>
<product>
<sku></sku>
<quantity></quantity>
</product>
</products>
</root>                                                                                                       This product element should repeat which contains sku & quantity.Please help.

Comment: According to your XSD `<orderNumber/>` and `<referenceNumber/>` must appear before `<products>` . So that XML should not be valid.

Comment: Sorry for missing those elements in XML,but tell me how to repeat product element

Comment: Your XSD is valid to repat `<product>` element. I don't see where is the problem.

Comment: @serigoFC-Where might me the problem??How can i solve this issue.

Comment: there is no issue at all. Please edit your post, if you don't know how to generate instance document from schema.

Answer (score 0):

Using your xsd, the following XML will be valid:

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="issue.xsd">
    <customReference></customReference>
    <shippedFromCustomId></shippedFromCustomId>
    <shippedToCustomId></shippedToCustomId>
    <orderNumber></orderNumber>
    <referenceNumber></referenceNumber>
    <products>
        <product>
            <sku></sku>
            <quantity></quantity>
        </product>
        <product>
            <sku></sku>
            <quantity></quantity>
        </product>
        <product>
            <sku></sku>
            <quantity></quantity>
        </product>
    </products>
</root>
```

Comment: @Win.ubuntu-This is what i am also using na.